# R group rows based on a value of specific column and keep lower and greater value on others columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe

```
library(data.table)

test_df=data.frame(chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr2","chr2","chr1","chr1","chr2","chr1"),
                   start=c(700,800,900,350,400,650,800,200,1000),
                   end=c(750,850,950,400,450,700,850,250,1050),
                   id=c("id_1","id_1","id_1","id_2","id_2","id_1","id_1","id_2","id_3"))
```

I'm trying to groups the rows by ID column.
For rows which have same values in chr and id, keep the lower value of start column and greater value for end column.

I expect for this dataframe something like :

```
chr     start     end     id
chr1     650      950     id_1
chr1     1000     1050    id_3
chr2     200      450     id_2
```

I tried this :

```
final_test_df=setDF(setDT(test_df)[, .(chr=chr[1],start=start[1], end=end[.N]),by=id])
```

and it gives me the first and last value for same id, not the lower/greater values.

```
id     chr     start     end
id_1   chr1     700      850     
id_2   chr2     350      250 
id_3   chr1     1000     1050
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by both *chr* and *id*, then get min/max for star/end:

```
test_df[, .(start = min(start), end = max(end)), by = .(id, chr) ]
#     id  chr start  end
#1: id_1 chr1   650  950
#2: id_2 chr2   200  450
#3: id_3 chr1  1000 1050
```

Same using *dplyr*:

```
test_df %>%
  group_by(id, chr) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end))
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups:   id [2]
#   id    chr   start   end
#   <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 id_1  chr1    650   950
# 2 id_2  chr2    200   450
# 3 id_3  chr1   1000  1050
```

Comment: Thank you it's working with dplyr. But the first one look to don't work.
Btw I edited my question and only ID is unique so I need to group only on ID

Comment: @Nono_sad check the output for data.table solution, it is exactly as your expected output.

Comment: Fwiw, the data.table way will use GForce, probably improving performance

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a dplyr package,

```
test_df %>% group_by(chr) %>% 
mutate(mymin = min(start), mymax = max(end), myunique = unique(id)) %>% 
select(mymin, mymax, myunique) %>% distinct
```

Comment: This work but actually I edit my question. Only ID is unique. I can have different ID for same chr.

By adaptating your code : 

test_df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(mymin = min(start), mymax = max(end), mychr = unique(chr)) %>% 
  select(mymin, mymax, mychr) %>% distinct

Comment: I felt like it - but in the example there were identification - anyway, let me know if you need other changes. Although dplyr can be slower but it is much easier to read and debug than datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
test_df=data.frame(chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr2","chr2","chr1","chr1","chr2"),
                   start=c(700,800,900,350,400,650,800,200),
                   end=c(750,850,950,400,450,700,850,250),
                   id=c("id_1","id_1","id_1","id_2","id_2","id_1","id_1","id_2"))

setDT(test_df)
test_df[,.(chr=chr[1],start=start[order(start)][1], end=end[order(end)][.N]), by=id]
```

using the original data,id and chr seems duplicated info